# Can a mocked domain "instance" be used in the controllers' show() method?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I am trying to pass a mocked domain instance called **event** to the controllers' *show()* method, but *show()* cannot find the Event in question and thus returns null.

Note that the following snippet is still work in progress.

```
def "trying to show an event containing malicous code"() {
    given: "An event named with malicous code"
    mockDomain(Event)
    def event   = Mock(Event)
    event.title >> "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"XSS\");</script>"
    event.id    >> 1
    // Do I have to actually create a full-blown event considering all
    // constraints here?

    when: "I try to show that event"
    controller.params.id    = 1
    def result = controller.show()

    then: "The resulting title will be encoded HTML"
    result.eventInstance.title    == event.title.encodeAsHTML()
}
```

This is the beginning of the controllers' show() method:

```
def show = {
    def eventInstance = Event.get(params.id)

    // The event exists
    if (eventInstance) {
            // some processing here

            return [eventInstance: eventInstance, isSubscribed: sub ? true:false, sidebar: 'sidebar']
    }
```

1. Is there a simple solution or will I have to actually create a full-blown event taking care of all constraints?
2. **If** I have to create a full event, where would I place the according method? (We're using a **createEvent()** method in BootStrap.groovy at the moment for initial setup, thus it wouldn't be DRY to repeat the function here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mocking the Event object in the following way:

```
def event   = new Event()
event.title = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"XSS\");</script>"
event.id    = 1 // optional 
mockDomain Event, [event]
```

Unless you add an instance of `event` to the `mockDomain` call, you won't be able to retrieve it with `get`

Comment: Thanks especially for the hint on adding the instance to the `mockDomain`-call. I've kept wondering what difference it made until today.

Comment: As a little proof to the above:

`def e = new Event(); assert !e.id; mockDomain Event, [e]; assert e.id == 1`

Comment: mfloryan, is there a way to assign the instance later on? - So that I can keep the basic `mockDomain Event` in the `setup()` and only add the instance to it, if needed?

Comment: @user569825 Yes, you can - simply create a new object and save it. Once you've mocked your domain object this should work fine.